# Accessing Unity-specific functionality in .NET Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, unity-container

I have a .net core 2.1 console app. I'm building the container as below:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    // Register services here.

    // Unity container interface:
    var containerFactory = new ServiceProviderFactory(null);
    IUnityContainer container = containerFactory.CreateBuilder(services);
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = containerFactory.CreateServiceProvider(container);

    return serviceProvider;
}
```

I need to provide constructor arguments to some of the services registered in the container. However, I do not want to use something like [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Instead, I would like to access the Unity functionality with something like below:

```
var container = (UnityContainer)serviceProvider;
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(new ParameterOverrides<Foo> { "name": "myFoo" });
```

The above approach is not working and throw the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider' to type 'Unity.UnityContainer'.
```

Is there a way to do this or am I restricted to `IServiceProvider` interface even though I'm using Unity implementation?

EDIT:

So, I can't find a way to switch from `IServiceProvider` to `IUnityContainer` with something like a cast. So, I changed the above code a bit to return Unity container instead:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    // Register services here.

    // Unity container interface:
    var containerFactory = new ServiceProviderFactory(null);
    IUnityContainer container = containerFactory.CreateBuilder(services);

    return container;
}
```

Now, I can use the usual Unity DI in the .Net Core App.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NugetPackage which integrates Unity with ServiceProvider provided by .NET Core.
https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection